# UTF8 icons in canvas

Tags: html, canvas, font-awesome

I would like to render

http://www.utf8icons.com/character/61505/UTF-8-character

Onto a canvas context. Is this an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is to use `String.fromCharCode`

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.width = canvas.height = 200;

ctx.font="100px Arial";
ctx.fillText(String.fromCharCode(61505), 50,100);
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/yacgm/)**

Comment: This works and so does "\uF041," as mentioned by torazaburo, which is preferable because It's a little more concise and consistent with the CSS code. Thanks much!

Comment: If for some reason you're really keen on using `String.fromCharCode`, but you want to use the hex representation for consistency with CSS or whatever, then it's just `String.fromCharCode(0xF041)`. See JS specification at http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/, definition of *HexIntegerLiteral*.

Comment: @torazaburo Im not sure why I got the accepted answer to be honest. I prefer your solution.

Answer (score 1):

What's the problem? It's just another character. There's no need to use fromCharCode at all. Just put the character in your code:

```
ctx.fillText(""...
```

Or, maybe if your editor doesn't support entry or display of such characters, then you'd prefer

```
ctx.filltext("\uF041",
```

Comment: The latter works, the former did not.

SublimeText2 for reference.

Comment: How does it not work in SublimeText? Have you set the encoding for the file properly?